# Intel Fortran not working with MS Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I tried downloading Intel Parallel Studio XE 2019 (which was free for me since I'm a student) to use with MS Visual Studio Community 2019, and I completed the installation with the cluster installer or whatever it's called (with one warning about how something wouldn't work, don't remember what it was exactly but it didn't seem very important for what I was trying to do). I opened Visual Studio and everything was going fine, until I wrote a "hello world" program and tried to get output from it. Looking at the debugger it seems like everything went fine, however the console only momentarily pops up and immediately closes, without printing anything. Could something be wrong with my installation? Did I forget something? Maybe the warning I got was important?

Answer (score 2):

Uh... Ok so this is kinda embarrassing... I just figured it out, I simply pressed "start without debugging" and everything worked fine!